# Float two divs side by side but let text continue flowing under?

Tags: html, css, overflow, fill

I have two divs:

```
#left{overflow: hidden;}
#right{float: right; width: 300px; margin: 0 0 0 20px;}

<div id='right'><p>Content</p></div>
<div id='left'><p>Content</p></div>
```

I have figured that much out as far as floating both divs side by side but allowing the left div to fill the remaining area.

My question now is:

As the screen becomes smaller, or someone views my site from a smaller screen/device, the text in my left div remains in a very long column extending far beyond that of the height of the right column.

I want to keep both divs side by side, with the left content filling the remaining area, but once the content in the left passes the length of the content in the right div, is there a way for it to then flow under the right div? Rather than to extend beyond?

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCwo.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow:hidden` from the left div and set a width.

Here is the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvGamX) try resizing the window.

Comment: The overflow: hiddren and lack of width is required for the text to fill the area. I am not using a contain: but instead am containing my content and sidebar within box-sizing: the text must flow until reaching the sidebar (right) but at the same time must flow beneath - no width.